# Built-in disc burning software in Windows 10

Tags: windows, dvd, windows-10

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 recently, and am looking to burn some .iso files. In Windows 7, there was a default program that I could use. I have dug around a bit, but cannot find one in Windows 10 so far. Although, a bunch of search functionality seems to be disabled on my machine, so I may just be searching incorrectly.

Is there a disc image burning program bundled in Windows 10 like there was in Windows 7?

Image of what I see:[image: Explorer]

Comment: This has been a feature of Windows since Windows XP.  You have been able mount .ISO since Windows 8.0

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you single click an ISO file using File Explorer "Disk Image Tools/Manage" shows up in the ribbon (much like MS office 2007 and later).  If you click on "Manage" two options should appear below.  Selecting "Burn" will give you the tool that you are looking for.

You should also be able to right click the file and select "Burn disc image" in the menu.

[image: Example]

If you have a program like VCD associated with ISO files the options above will not show up.

**Supplementary trick**: to restore the tab showing up in the ribbon, you do not need to un-install anything: just reassociate .ISO with Explorer (right-click on any .ISO, Open with... submenu, select File Explorer and check the Always use... box; you can do the same thing with the Associate control panel).

Comment: I don't seem to have a `Manage` tab, just `File`|`Home`|`Share`|`View`. When I right click on it, there is also no option to burn. I've added a link to what I see in the OP.

Comment: That's odd.  Do you have the pro or home version?  I have the pro version.

Comment: I have the Pro version. I had W7 Professional before the upgrade as well.

Comment: Shot in the dark here but it could be the association with virtual clone drive that is causing the options I mentioned not to show up.

Comment: I'll be damned. I uninstalled VCD (I don't use it often anymore) and it showed up.

Comment: Supplementary trick: to restore the tab showing up in the ribbon, you do not need to un-install anything: just reassociate .ISO with Explorer (right-click on any .ISO, Open with... submenu, select File Explorer and check the Always use... box; you can do the same thing with the Associate control panel). So +1 for @Solitz which aimed pretty well in the dark!

Comment: @AntoineL : why, Microsoft, why? Why do we even have to do that? That's so illogical.

Comment: +1 for sorting out the file association issue.  I hate to think how many people have purchased disc burning software due to this.

Comment: File Explorer --> Open With --> Choose Another App --> Windows Explorer and Check `Always Use`   Many thanks to Solitz!

Answer (score 42):

For others, who don't have the "Manage" tab in Explorer, use "Open With" -> "Other application" -> select "c:\windows\system32\isoburn.exe"

Comment: This suggestion did not work in my system. Probably, some privilege problem or something else.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, man.  I can't believe how MS hides this feature.  Why on earth is it not accessible via the right-mouse click menu?

Comment: This saved my bacon, I wasn't getting the manage option. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: This didn't work but I was able to run it from cmd prompt instead and pass in the name of the file

Comment: This worked for me on Win 10 Home upgraded from Win 7, where the accepted answer did not. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sitting at a W10 machine, but the way I did it in W8.1 was:

```
Right-click -> Open with -> Windows Explorer
```

Then I selected all the files (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

```
Share ribbon -> Burn to disc
```

Comment: That option didn't show up under share.

Comment: What about Send To -> Disk drive?

Comment: Nope, stopped at Desktop. It was the VCD association that wasn't allowing anything to show up. I removed it, and everything works now.

Comment: -1 ... What about bootable iso files?